# How to change URL in JavaScript without storing in browser's history

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, browser-history

I want to change the URL in javascript without affecting browser's history.
I have this URL in

```
http://abcd.com/parent/child/?id=xyz abc
```

it's a WordPress URL I want this

`http://abcd.com/newurl/xyz ABC`

I am using `history.replaceState` function in javascript to change the URL its working fine but whenever I click on the back button from browsers or refresh the page it redirects me from current page to the home page.

What I want, it should store the original URL( `http://abcd.com/parent/child/?id=xyz abc`) and show this URL to user (`http://abcd.com/newurl/xyz ABC`)

I just want to change the URL, not history.
here is my javascript code

```
history.replaceState('', 'my title', 'http://abcd.com/newurl/<?php echo str_replace(" ","-",$_GET["id"]); ?>');
```

`$_GET["id"]` is a stirng xyz ABC

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function changeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = {Page: title, Url: url};
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
    }
}
```

Comment: its working fine but whenever I click on the back button its just show the old URL but not redirecting me. but when I second click on the back button from the browser it redirects me to the home page. Is there any way to change the URL...? I am solving this problem since a week but still facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going the wrong way. Instead of doing this in JavaScript, you should solve it in WordPress with a custom rewrite rule.

Read More here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

**Detailed Solution:**

For example you want the url `http://example.com/india/?id=vip/` to be `http://example.com/india/vip/`

where `india` is the `page slug` and `id` is your query variable.

Add the following code to your `functions.php` file:

```
function add_query_vars($queryVars) {
    $queryVars[] = "id"; // represents the name of the string as shown in the URL
    return $queryVars;
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('india/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=india&id=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

And in your code say `page.php` you can use the variable like

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['id'])) {
    $testid = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['id']);
}
echo $testid;
```

**NOTE:** Please make sure to reset permalink after you change the above things.

Comment: how can I do this could you please tell me I am new in WordPress that's why I am facing the problem.

Comment: http://example.com/pagename/?id=VIP Text pagename is a custom page I fetching the data from database using GET['id'] how to can I convert my URL  http://example.com/Newpagename/VIP Text

Comment: please check the updated answer. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: I have this URL now http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP%20Airliner I paste your code into my functions.php file but it's not working I don't know why

Comment: #KiranDash are you there..?

Comment: What is your url and what are you expecting it to be?

Comment: I have this URL http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIPAirliner and I want this URL http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/VIP-Airliner

Comment: could you please solve this problem I am facing this problem since 1 week but still finding the solution

Comment: example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP-Airliner 
will be
example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/VIP-Airliner
if you use my above code and change india to aircraft-gallery-class and then reset your permalink once

Comment: I want to convert this URL http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP Airliner into this http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/VIP-Airliner

Comment: #Kiran Dash its not working i paste this code if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['id'])) {
    $testid = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['id']);
}
echo $testid; //in my this page aircraft-gallery-class but its returning NULL vlaue

Comment: did you reset permalink after adding the code? After you added the code, go to settings->permalinks->select post name option and click on save

Comment: yes, whenever I change the code in functions.php file for URL purpose I save the Permalink button.